# I have zones sorted by the kmeans algo. I want the zones as areas (like a polygon). How to do that?

Tags: python, google-maps, matplotlib, plot, k-means

[image: Zones with centers already created by k means algorithm]

I want to create a polygon(the points are the ones indicated in the figure) for each zone in the figure (please refer to the figure above). Can you help me in figuring out how to that?

PS: I also have the POINTS(GPS co-ordinates) of all of them plotted.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant with "polygon". You what to plot a the points inside a polygon? Or just create clusters for each zone?

Comment: I mean to join all the points in a cluster make it look a polygon. So there will be many polygons in the end so that each polygon refers to each cluster.

Comment: I think you are looking for a convex hull https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But what if I want do that plot on the maps directly?

Answer (score 0):

Compute the Delaunay Triangulation of the cluster centers. The dual of this are the Voronpi cells, and these correspond *exactly* to the clusters found by k-means.

However, these cells will go to infinity. In your case with just k=2, you get a simple bisector: the Delaunay Triangulation of two points is simply their connection line. Then draw the line perpendicular at the midpoint of the two centers. This separates the plane into two areas, these are your clusters.

In many cases, the convex hull will be easier to handle, although it does not show the cluster separations that precisely.

For geographic data, k-means also is not the best choice: 1) it is not robust to outliers, and you frequently have some points that shouldn't be in clusters 2) it uses squared errors, not distance. Squared errors do not have a particular intuitive meaning in geography (traveling twice as far will usually take twice as long, not four times!) and when used on latitude and longitude, it causes a bias unless you are always close to the equator and not at +-180.